# TextView values are switched around

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I'm just making a simple weather application using Android, and I am making a drawer with a custom listview - which displays the city, time, current temperature, and icon of a location in the database. But, in my ListView Adapter, when I set my values of the textviews, it comes out incorrectly. Basically, the values are getting switched around.

Ex - if i set Chicago as my city, it will show Chicago where the temperature is supposed to be.

DrawerListAdapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView city = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.city);
    TextView time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
    TextView temp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.temp);

    icon.setImageResource(drawerListItem.get(position).getIcon());
    city.setText(drawerListItem.get(position).getCity());
    time.setText(drawerListItem.get(position).getTime());
    temp.setText(drawerListItem.get(position).getTemp());

    return convertView;
}
```

DrawerListItem.java

```
public class DrawerListItem {
int icon;
String city;
String time;
String temp;

public DrawerListItem(int icon, String city, String time, String temp) {
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.city = city;
    this.time = time;
    this.temp = temp;
}

public int getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getTemp() {
    return temp;
}

public void setTemp(String temp) {
    this.temp = temp;
    }
}
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="58dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
android:minHeight="58dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/cloudy" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/temp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/temp_bg"
    android:text="75°"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/city"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon"
    android:text="3:17 PM"
    android:textColor="@color/White" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/city"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/time"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:text="Chicago"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: Where do you actually create the `DrawerListItem`?

Comment: In my main activity. I add the DrawerListItem into a ArrayList, then give the ArrayList to the Adapter. The Adapter then sets the values

Comment: This is where I learned how to make it: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is where you create your `DrawerListItem` instances.

Take, for example, Liconshire. You are calling the constructor like so:

```
new DrawerListItem(R.drawable.cloudy, "9:53 AM ,"73°", "Linconshire")
```

However, your constructor looks like this:

```
DrawerListItem(int icon, String city, String time, String temp)
```

Thus your are creating a drawer list item with the following arguments:

- icon: `R.drawable.cloudy`
- city: `"9:53 AM"`
- time: `"73°"`
- temp: `"Linconshire"`

Change the order of your arguments to match the order that you specified in the constructor, and it will show up correctly. For example, `new DrawerListItem(R.drawable.cloudy, "Linconshire", "9:53 AM", "73°")`

Comment: Well, I was trying to switch the code around, to get it to work. That was the code where the values are set to the right textViews. If I put them in order, they get switched around

Comment: `drawerItems.add(new DrawerListItem(R.drawable.cloudy, "Vernon Hills",
    "9:51 PM", "54°"));`

Comment: That is how it looks like in order

Comment: time goes to city textview, city goes to temp, and temp goes to time, icon stays on icon though